# Image in a fixed size box?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to display images in a **fixed size box** (the grey area in the image here). When the submit button is pressed new images will be fetched from the internet. But the images will be different sizes.

So to prevent the "submit" button moving up and down due to different size images (and potentially having it off the screen) I'd like the images to fit inside the box. (I suppose there are a few options there, for example having the image resize to fit in the box or having the image be clipped and still fitting in the box.) I've been messing with containers and columns etc for ages but nothing seems to work.

**what is the best way to fit images of different sizes into a fixed size box ?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Image` widget can have a height be specified. You can read more about that [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html)

Comment: It looks like the height has to be specified as a number. Can an image (or its container) be specified to be 50% of screen height?

Comment: You can use this double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2